# Show information when radio button is triggered

Tags: java

> I wanted the information to be shown when a radio button is clicked. The program look like this [program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJa4x.png). When I click one of the radio button and press ENTER, I should be getting the result on the right textfields but It seems like there was nothing displayed on the right textfields when i choose a radio button. There was no error in my code though. Other than that, I was able to choose both of the buttons, how can I set it as only one of the radio button will be true?

```
public class Q2 extends JFrame implements ItemListener{...}

    public Q2()
    {
        Font ft1 = new Font ("Dialog", Font.BOLD+Font.ITALIC,30);
        Font ft2 = new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD,15);
        
        
        lb2 = new JLabel("Calculate fee by:");
        lb2.setFont(ft1);
        
        rb1 = new JRadioButton("Kilometer (RM0.95 per/km)");
        lb1 = new JLabel("Welcome to MyTeksiSapu");
        lb1.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        lb1.setFont(ft1);
        lb3 = new JLabel("Distance to destination(km): ");
        tf1 = new JTextField(10);
        
        rb2 = new JRadioButton("Time (RM0.35 per/min)");
        lb4 = new JLabel("Distance to destination(mins): ");
        tf2 = new JTextField(10);
        
        lb5 = new JLabel("Calculated by: "); 
        tf3 = new JTextField(10);
        tf3.setFont(ft2);
        tf3.setForeground(Color.red);
        tf3.setOpaque(false);
        
        lb6 = new JLabel("Total: RM ");
        tf4 = new JTextField(10);
        tf4.setFont(ft2);
        tf4.setForeground(Color.red);
        tf4.setOpaque(false);
        
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.add(lb1);
        p1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        JPanel subp2 = new JPanel();
        subp2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,3));
        subp2.add(rb1);subp2.add(lb3);subp2.add(tf1);
        subp2.add(rb2);subp2.add(lb4);subp2.add(tf2);
        
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        p2.add(lb2);
        p2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        p2.add(subp2);
      
        JPanel subp3 = new JPanel();
        subp3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        subp3.add(lb5);subp3.add(tf3);
        subp3.add(lb6);subp3.add(tf4);
        
        JPanel p3 = new JPanel();
        p3.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("taxicar.jpg"));
        JLabel taxicar = new JLabel(icon);
        p3.add(taxicar);
        p3.setBackground(Color.white);
        p3.add(subp3);

        add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p2,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(p3,BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        double km = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
        double mins = Double.parseDouble(tf2.getText());
        double total = 0;
        
        if(rb1.isSelected())
        {
            tf3.setText("Meter");
            total = 0.95*km;
            tf3.setText(df.format(total));
        }
        if(rb2.isSelected())
        {
            tf3.setText("Time");
            total = 0.95*mins;
            tf3.setText(df.format(total));
        }
    }
```

Comment: A [mre] would help immensely. The link will explain what I'm requesting and how creating and posting one can help both you and us

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i have updated the question, hope it helps.

Comment: I don't see where you add the listener to the button.

Comment: @WJS i added it in the public class.

Comment: You're implementing the listener.  But I still don't see where you are adding the listener to the buttons.  `button.addItemListener(this)` or something similar.

Comment: Yikes -- just creating a listener is worthless if it is not added to something and listens to something

Comment: And @WJS's comment is *exactly* why an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so useful

Comment: You should check out [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).  It covers quite a bit of the basic topics including event handling, painting, layout managers, etc.  Unfortunately, it is limited to Java 8 and before.

Comment: @Priscilla your frame doesn't need to implement `ItemListener` because IT doesn't have to react to any events, your radio buttons are. They need to implement ActionListener. The best thing you can do is implement a private class that implements that action listener and add the listener to both radio buttons. You also need to add both radio buttons to a `ButtonGroup` so that deselection is done automatically. Lastly, add an action command that's unique to each button. Your action listener needs to convert the event's object into a radio button and based on which button it is, kick off the logic

Comment: @hfontanez  NO!  They don't need to implement `actionListener`.   `ItemListener` works just fine and is actually appropriate for Radio Buttons.  Why are you telling the OP to switch?

Comment: @WJS the main point I made is that the listener, whichever you prefer, doesn't belong in the `JFrame`. This is confirmed by my opening statement in the comment. That should answer your question. Also, `ActionListener` is the main listener used with buttons in general. Whether is it appropriate or not, I won't argue that point. But, I would argue that may not be the preferred choice industry-wide.

Comment: @hfontanez  Got it.  And I agree!

Comment: @WJS I wish they would've kept this question open. I had a laundry list of things wrong with this implementation beyond the functionality of the radio buttons and the fact that the listener was implemented and not added to any entity.

Comment: @hfontanez I reopened the question.  Not certain if it is appropriate to do so but since we participate to help, it shouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the simple functionality of an application (works vs. doesn't work), there are general guidelines and principles that should be observed to ensure the best possible performance is achieved when creating an application. I have a few observations on what's wrong with this application beyond the OP's question

#### Responsibility of components

The first mistake I found with the OP's implementation was with the assigned responsibilities of the `JFrame`. In a swing application, the responsibility of the `JFrame` should be limited to provide main container for the application itself. With these, there are some derived responsibilities that I won't get into. However, I would say that the `JFrame` is not responsible to act as a middle man between Events and Components. Therefore, in this context, `JFrame implements ItemListener` is clearly a mistake. When you look at what the `itemStateChanged` method does, it obvious that it doesn't belong there. Moreover, if the `JFrame` ever needs to execute some logic based on changes in its own state, the implementation of this method will be forced to add a new responsibility to it; violating SOLID's Single Responsibility Principle. On the other hand, if the implementation of the listener is limited to the *radio buttons*, it his very unlikely this will change in the future. For now, let's assume that the radio buttons will need to implement `ItemListener` (although I will argue against this shortly).

1. To fix this code, you could simply add an anonymous listener to the
   buttons directly. Search the web for details on how to do this.
2. You could also opt to create your own class that extends
   `JRadioButton` where your specialized class can address all of the
   dependencies your components will need for your application or
   project. For homework (like this one appears to be) this is not
   necessary.
3. A better option to anonymous listeners, is to create a private class
   that implements the desired listener.

   public class MyClass {
   ...
   private class MyListener implements .... {
   // implemented methods here
   }
   }

Then, your component can simply create an instance of `MyListener` and use it in as many components that might need it OR create as many instances of `MyListener` and assigned to specific components, but this looks like anonymous listeners would be better.

#### Expected behavior of radio buttons

Radio buttons are buttons (remember this point). However, they are a specialized form of buttons. When people see radio buttons, they expect that the selection of a radio button automatically deselects the previously selected buttons. This application doesn't do that. In this example, both radio buttons can be in the selected state at the same time. This behavior is expected from `JCheckBox`, but not from `JRadioButton`. In order for radio buttons to activate the behavior I just described, they must be added to a `ButtonGroup`.

```
ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
group.add(rb1);
group.add(rb2);
```

Once this is done, controlling the deselection of previously selected button in the group is handled automatically. Besides the point of this being how most people expect radio buttons to behave like, this application **requires** this behavior. Why, because text fields set the text they are supposed to display based on the EXCLUSIVE selection of one of the radio buttons. For this application, one text field is responsible to display whether the taxi fare was calculated based on *distance* **OR** *time*; not both.

Lastly, typically one of the radio buttons will be selected by default. HOWEVER, in this context, I think it is OK for the application to launch with both deselected. Doing this will eliminate the confusion of seeing one selected and no text in the fields that get populated based on radio button's selection.

#### Event Listeners

Event listeners are at the heart of ***Event-Driver Programming***, which is basically how modern applications are built. Java Swing framework has a very robust set of listeners for almost all situations. In my many years working Swing applications, I don't recall a time where I designed my own listener.

Remember I stated earlier that "radio buttons are buttons" and that I also wrote about "responsibility of components"? I stated that to frame why I oppose the use of `ItemListener` for triggering the logic of what happens when a radio button is selected. From the `ItemSelectable` interface (which `AbstractButton` extends), this interface was created or designed to address the following responsibility:

> The interface for objects which contain a set of items for which zero or more can be selected

Based on that, you can see this sounds very close to what `ButtonGroup` does. If you examine this class, you can see why `AbstractButton` extends this interface. `ButtonGroup` needs it in order to "create a multiple-exclusion scope for a set of buttons." This is how radio buttons assigned to a button group get automatically deselected when another one is selected. Could the same listener be used to fire off the logic to update the text fields based on the radio button that is selected? Yes, it can be done this way. But based on the listener's documentation, this wasn't the reason why it was created.

My suggestion is to implement `ActionListener` instead. This class is not only a general-purpose listener, it is the one recommended by the designers of the Swing framework to handle such events. In this case, my solution is very simple:

```
private class RadioSelectionListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        JRadioButton rb = (JRadioButton)e.getSource(); // As the creator, I know this listener is added to radio buttons only. So, the assumption is safe
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

        double km = Double.parseDouble(tf1.getText());
        double mins = Double.parseDouble(tf2.getText());
        double total = 0;

        if (rb.getActionCommand().equals("km")) {
            tf3.setText("Meter");
            total = 0.95 * km;
        } else {
            tf3.setText("Time");
            total = 0.95 * mins;
        }

        tf4.setText(df.format(total)); // This was set on tf3 in the OP's code which is wrong
    }
}
```

In order for this solution to work, the same instance of `ActionListener` should be added and an "action command" should be assigned to each button. Although this is not necessary, it makes it much easier to know which of the button is associated with the event's source (as you can see in my code snippet above). Therefore, somewhere in the application, the following lines must be added:

```
    rb1.setActionCommand("km");
    rb2.setActionCommand("time");

    ActionListener listener = new RadioSelectionListener();
    rb1.addActionListener(listener);
    rb2.addActionListener(listener);
```

#### "Never" extend JFrame

I typed the word never inside quotes because this is not a rule set in stone. This is more of a personal preference, but one I find to be shared by a whole lot of people. Instead, you should create an "app" class that contains a `JFrame` along with the rest of the components. This "app" should be the class containing the `main` method to launch your app. The recommended approach to do this is the following:

```
public class MyApp {

  public static void main (String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        
      @Override
        public void run () {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }

        private void createAndShowGUI () {
          // construct and add your frame and other items here.
        }
    });
  }
}
```

#### Summary

Remember Single Responsibility Principle and assign responsibility where it belongs. Here, the components that need to be registered to receive notification when they are clicked are the buttons themselves, not the frame.

Encapsulate behavior and attributes in classes to improve usability. It also improves readability. In this case, the frame should not be a "god class" with hundreds lines of code.

Lastly, implement behaviors that closely match the expectations or mental models of the users. For radio buttons, only one in a group is expected to be selected at any given time. In fact, they got their name from old radios with preset buttons that, when pressed, they would change the station selection. Imagine how bad it would've been if radios allowed multiple stations to be selected at the same time?

There are a few more (minor) issues I would like to address, but this gone long enough... I included screenshots of the application working after my changes.

[image]

[image]